# How can I automatically load a new page after text input is entered

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a kiosk where people will come up and scan a QR code containing an 8 character confirmation number.

After they scan their QR code, and their confirmation number is populated into a text field, I would like to automatically redirect to another page. Is there a javascript function I can use to accomplish this?

I don't want them to have to click a submit button or anything to do this.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" name="confirm" id="scanner" autofocus="autofocus" value="" maxlength="8">
</form>
```

Comment: you mean window.location.href ?

Comment: you can use onchaange event which will be fired everytime value inside textbox gets changed. In that you can use window.location (@Ken Kwok) for valid inputto redirect to another page.

Comment: it has fire after all 8 characters of the confirmation number have been entered

Comment: @KenKwok yes, I can use that, but wondering how I can after the maxlength has been reached, or after a certain time interval

Comment: you can validate input for length and proper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var scanner = document.getElementById('scanner');

function checkLength(){
  if(scanner.value.length === 8){
    window.location.assign('http://stackoverflow.com')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="confirm" id="scanner" autofocus="autofocus" value="" maxlength="8" oninput="checkLength()">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i would do:

```
<html>
    <body>


        <form action="post.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="text" name="confirm" id="scanner" autofocus="autofocus" value="" maxlength="8">
        </form>


        <script>
            $("#scanner").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            });
        </script>


   </body>
</html>
```

this is assuming you are using JQuery

Comment: ah ok :P i just feel this is a clean and nice way to do it though

Comment: you cant write a submit event on input. provide form id for submit not input id. @FelipeGarcia-Diaz

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the onchange event: 
**HTML:**

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" name="confirm" id="scanner" autofocus="autofocus" value="" maxlength="8" onchange="newPage();">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function newPage(){
windows.location.href = www.yourlinkhere.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind('input propertychange','#scanner',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign('http://stackoverflow.com');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="post.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="form_submit">
        <input type="text" name="confirm" id="scanner" autofocus="autofocus" value="" maxlength="8">
</form>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.